# New Relic not sending data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, newrelic, linode

I've newrelic agent for my rails application installed on linode. App is using unicorn and i've did some magic (https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/no-data-with-unicorn), but still have no data on my dashboard. Other hand - i've migrated my app from heroku to linode and on heroku it's working fine (i've deleted old app profile from dashboard).

Could you give me any idea - how can i determine what the problem is?

Comment: By default Heroku injects the API key for NewRelic in the config/newrelic.yml file from its own configuration, if you migrated to Linode, did you also add the API key to the configuration file?

Comment: yeah - i'm using my own newrelic.yml file

Comment: there are no log :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution of my problem. It was because of i've forgot to remove from application config file some environment variables - NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME, NEW_RELIC_ID, NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY, NEW_RELIC_LOG.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to debug this situation, but the lack of newrelic log file seems there is some basic setup issue.

Try to go through the installation instructions again. If that does't help raise a support ticket with newrelic. They are a helpful bunch of people and you will get an answer quite fast.

Answer (score -1):

If you use new relic addons on heroku, your datas will be at https://heroku.newrelic.com . 
**Try to go the app resources and click on new relic addons.**

Comment: When I changed to JRuby and Puma webserver, my app didnt send data for new relicc because it was configured for MRI and Thin. Check out Settings >> Environment that everything is correct.